# What's $E[\frac{X}{\Vert X \Vert}]$ if $E[X]=0$?

Tags: probability, hilbert-spaces, expected-value

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $S(x)=\begin{cases} x/\Vert x \Vert & x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0  \end{cases}$ be the spatial sign function with $\Vert x\Vert$ the induced norm of the inner product of $H$.
Given a random variable $X$ in H with $E[X]=0$, does it follow that $E[S(X)]=0$ as well? 
I want to keep it as general as possible, i.e. if possible, not assume the existence of a density function or other distribution characteristics.
I have the strong feeling that it holds due to the definition of the spatial sign function that is zero exactly at zero but can neither prove nor disprove this. I am thankful for any comment/idea!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $\|X\|$ ? Is it $\sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]}$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=-1$ with probbaility $2/3$ and $X=2$ with probaility $1/3$ then $EX=0$ but $E\frac X {|X|} \neq 0$.

Comment: Isn't  $E\frac X {|X|} =  2/3\cdot (-1)+1/3\cdot 2=0$?

Comment: @callculus42 Your factor of $2$ should be $1$.

Comment: @J.G. O.K.  Thanks for your comment. Ouch.

Comment: Huh, I was really thinking too complicated. Thanks!